# CNN Image Classification with multiple input images for one record

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've got a dataset containing of **20,000** cars and **80,000** images.

- Each car is represented by a 4 images.
- 10,000 cars are in perfect shape, without any damage (first folder)
- 10,000 cars are damaged and at least one of 4 images has a visible damage to the car (second folder)

In my mind I can see at least two approaches:

1. Create one big image from four images and create a matrix representation
2. **Create an input where one car (one observation) is represented by 4 inputs.**
3. Manually tag images, where the car is damaged.

Personally I would like to go with option **2** - but I don't know how to implement this input.

I wanted to stack images like when using RGB channels, but I know that CNNs are going in-depth, so I assume this could cause some problems while training.

Is there another way to implement multi-image input ? So for one car (observation / car) I can specify four different matrices ?

__

**EDIT:**

I only have information, that the car is damaged. I do now know which image(s) contain the damaged parts.

Answer (score 0):

The **option 2** of using 4 channels should work, but it looks overcomplicating the problem, both from the input and for the training perspective. Same happens with **option 1**.

For me it seems that you want a algorithm that identifies damages car's pictures, and for such task I think the best approach is training on one channel labelling each image.

**The option 3** has many advantages:

1. Will make the model smaller.
2. Will make the training easier.
3. From 1 and 2 you could expect better accuracy for your spent time.
4. Will make your model more robust to unexpected inputs.

Let's say now you only have 2 or 5 pictures of each car, or simply there is a image in the group that is not a car, with the channel option or the "Big matrix" option, you would need to develop some strategies on top to handle those cases.

If you instead make a generic picture crash recognition algorithm, you run it over the 4 or n pictures of one car, and as long as one of them shows damage then you predict a damage.

The main disadvantage is that labelling 10k pictures seems like a bunch of work, but they should have been labelled picture by picture in the first place and not in 4 pictures clusters.

**Other option** could be developing a unsupervised learning algorithm, that discovers the differences between a damaged a undamaged car without using tags, but this could make also the train harder and the model more complex if you already have labels.

Comment: Yea that all makes sense, but unfortunately I only have information about car being damaged, without knowledge of which specific image contains damaged car. So basically I would need to go one by one of those 40,000 images and label them accordingly

Comment: Yes, I understood that, and it is really unfortunate, but my answer doesn't change, as there is no magical solution to your problem, you will need to choose a trade-off. For me it seems that option 3 is far better than 1 and 2.

Comment: But 2 will also work, the input will be the same as an RGB image but with 4 channels instead of 3, not sure what is the question regarding that. For convolutions you can keep the depth out, there is no issue there, basically treat them as separate inputs till the final sigmoid layer. If you have problems doing this, it is another question by itself.

Comment: And 4 different matrixes and 4 different channels is just the same concept.. You can also concatenate images or average them etc and it may work, but I don't think you will be doing it better.

You are basically asking how to do a good model poorly labelled data. Don't forget the principle Garbage in, garbage out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out